# Reptilian aliens in human form shed their skin as they board their mothership

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Looking for an old sci fi from 60's? 70's? About reptilian aliens
that have human exteriors and green blood.

At the end of the movie, all the aliens are lined up to get on the
Mother Ship to go home, and shed their human skins as they board.

Comment: Sounds reminiscent of the 2 part miniseries of the original "V", but not quite close enough.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 3):

The description reminds me of *Strange Invaders* (1983) which has a scene near the end where aliens shed their human forms and board a ship to go home.  I don't remember if the aliens are reptilian, though.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this might be the 80's original "V" series. The aliens were reptilian and had green blood. Did the aliens wear red and black uniforms?